# "Access is denied" error running Group Policy Results Wizard

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Domain Admins could run Group Policy Results Wizard in domain but another user with delegated permission on "Read Group Policy Results Data" couldn't run the wizard for the same clients.The user have full control permission on clients OU ([modify permission is necessary](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn789195(v=ws.11).aspx#Anchor_4)) but he encounters "You don't have permission to perform this operation. Access is denied "

[image]

Is being Domain Admins or local Administrator necessary for running the wizard?

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](http://beta.itprotoday.com/security/two-generate-resultant-set-policy-permissions?utm_test=redirect&utm_referrer=https%3A//www.bing.com/) it appears you need to grant Generate Resultant Set of Policy (Logging) right.

Comment: The user already has that permission on clients OU.

Answer (score 0):

I added the user to the client Administrators which he wants to run RSOP wizard on and it worked.So yes it needs to be local admin on clients which you want to remotely run RSOP wizard.